# How to 'break' a big JSON file

Tags: json

I'm working with a huge JSON file.

And I need to display it on a web page.
I'm thinking in 'breaking' or 'paginate' that file.

Which way is the best for it?

e.g: JSON file

```
     {
       key1: 'value1',
       key2: 'value2',
       key3: 'value3',
       key4: 'value4',
       key5: ['value','valeu'],
       key6: 'value',
       key7: 10, 
         **...**
     }
```

**EDIT:** I'm reading a `.txt` file. more than 100mb of data information (data mining and machine learning project, using python)

**EDIT2:** Paginate is to load parts of the object when is needed, not to load all the `.txt`,e.g: click nextPage() than loads more of the json file.

Comment: which technology are you using to parse it? How large is the file?

Comment: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-coantrol-characters/form-feed-female-symbol-venus-ascii-code-12.html

Comment: Would changing the object to an array structure work? Are you planing on re-combining the object?

Comment: just updated the question  @shafeen

Comment: @YourFriendKen I'm just planing to read for now